# Why element.removeAttribute('selected') not work?

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge

Source code http://jsfiddle.net/51p7ocLw/

I tried to create `<select>` tag with multyselect but the problem is that in regular you have to push Ctrl to select a few. Now with this function I resolve that problem. But there arise new one. It's not removing `selected` attribute from element when I'm calling `el.removeAttribute('selected')`

NOTE: code works on chrome but not works on Edge but I need it to work on both of them!

Comment: The fiddle works fine though?

Comment: Don't know if I'm missing something, but it is removing the tag in the example

Comment: It works on chrome but nowhere else

Comment: its not working on Edge. but I need it to work on both of them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `selected` state of an option is not an *attribute* but a *property*.

Instead of `el.removeAttribute('selected')`, use `el.selected = false`.

To toggle, simply use:

```
el.selected = !el.selected;
```

Comment: Well the source works on chrome but deny to work on edge as well as your code

Comment: [This works in Edge, when I try it](http://jsfiddle.net/wg7ebmhr/). (In IE 11, however, it doesn't work, because `e.target` refers to the `select`)